# Toggle Lock screen

Tags: applications, lock-screens

How to easily enable / disable the lock screen on nougat? So that I can remove
the lock screen when I frequently use the phone and enable when I leave the phone somewhere.

Comment: Would something like [Android's Smart-Lock functionality](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+smart-lock) (introduced with Lollipop) fit for that? It can e.g. change that setting based on location or nearby networks. If you carry another device with you that e.g. uses Bluetooth, that might be used as well (disable lock when near). Another possibility: Something NFC, ideally an [NFC ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_ring) on the hand you usually hold the device in, so NFC could trigger the "unlock". Same goes for a smart watch.

Answer (score 0):

The lock screen can only be changed in the settings. You can use smart Lock if you have a Bluetooth device, like a smart watch. You could also turn off instant lock, and set it to five minutes or so. That way when you are frequently using your device, you aren't prompted every time.